# Python logging; [1] cannot set log file dirpath; and [2] datetime formatting problems

Tags: python-3.x, logging, python-datetime

I am trying to learn how to use the logging module.
I want to log information to both console and to file.
I confess that I have not completed studying both https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig and https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

It's a little daunting for a novice like me to learn all of it, but I am working on it.

I am trying to use a modified version of the  “Logging to multiple destinations” program from https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html, to which I refer as “Cookbook_Code”.

The Cookbook_Code appears at that [URL](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) under the title "Logging to multiple destinations".

But I have two problems:

1. The Cookbook Code saves to a file named:
   "E:\Zmani\Logging\Logging_to_multiple_destinations_python.org_aaa.py.txt",
   and I cannot figure out:

   A. Why the Cookbook Code does that, nor

   B. How to make the logging module save instead to a the following filepath (which I stored in a var, "logfile_fullname"):  "e:\zmani\Logging\2020-10-14_14_14_os.walk_script.log"
2. I cannot figure out how to have the log file use the following datetime format:

   "YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS - INFO: Sample info."
   instead of the following datetime format: "10/14/2020 03:00:22 PM - INFO: Sample info."
3. I would like the console output include the same datetime prefix:
   "YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS -"

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

```
                         Marc
```

Here’s the code I have been running:

```
log_file_fullname = "e:\zmani\Logging\2020-10-14_14_14_os.walk_script.log"

# https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook

import logging
# set up logging to file - see previous section for more details
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S',
                    filename=log_file_fullname,
                    filemode='w')


console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')

console.setFormatter(formatter)

logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

  logging.info('Sample info.')
    
logger1 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area2')

logger1.debug('Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim.')
logger1.info('How quickly daft jumping zebras vex.')
logger2.warning('Jail zesty vixen who grabbed pay from quack.')
logger2.error('The five boxing wizards jump quickly.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick run of your code showed that it already does `1.B` and `2` of your problems.

Your provided URLs showed nowhere that `Logging_to_multiple_destinations_python.org_aaa.py.txt` is being used. It doesn't matter anyway. It just a path to a text file provided that its parent folders exist. So `1.A` is just merely a demonstration.

If you add `%(asctime)s` to the console's `formatter`, it will give you `3.`

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
```

---

You should only use `basicConfig` if you don't need to add any logger nor doing a complicated setup.

`basicConfig` will only have an effect if there aren't any handler in the `root` logger. If you use `filename` argument, it creates a `FileHandler`. If you use `stream` argument, it creates a `StreamHandler`. And you cannot use both arguments at once.

So you said that you need to output to file and console, just create a handler for each of them.

```
import logging

log_file_fullname = "2020-10-14_14_14_os.walk_script.log"

# config file handler
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file_fullname)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fmt_1 = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', 
                          datefmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
file_handler.setFormatter(fmt_1)

# config console handler
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fmt_2 = fmt_1                               # you could add console only formatter here
console_handler.setFormatter(fmt_2)

# retrieve a root logger and add handlers
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)        # change from default WARNING to NOTSET,
root_logger.addHandler(file_handler)        # this allows root_logger to take all propagated
root_logger.addHandler(console_handler)     # messages from other child loggers.


# this line use root logger by default
logging.info('Sample info.')

# create module loggers
logger1 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area2')

# logging by module loggers
logger1.debug('Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim.')
logger1.info('How quickly daft jumping zebras vex.')
logger2.warning('Jail zesty vixen who grabbed pay from quack.')
logger2.error('The five boxing wizards jump quickly.')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  But no good deed goes unpunished.  I made a function from your code, with parameters 'msg' and 'msg_type'. I inserted the following 2 lines: [LINE1: "if msg_type.lower() == 'error':"] AND [LINE2: "logging.error(msg)"]  For some reason that I cannot figure out, the error message appears twice in both the console and the log file.  Can you explain why that happens?

Comment: @MarcB.Hankin could you append the new code to your question?